# Ruby on Rails If...Else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
<div class="category_name">
     <%= current_user %>
     <%= review.user.front_name %>
      <% if current_user.name = review.user.front_name %>
      <%= link_to "You", user_path(review.user) %> / <%= review.categories_list %>
      <% else %>
      <%= link_to review.user.front_name, user_path(review.user) %> / <%= review.categories_list %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

It renders something like:

Tom Murphy
Bill Smith
You / Films

Why is this happening?

```
<% if current_user.name = review.user.front_name %>
```

In other words, if Tom Murphy = Bill Smith...which it doesn't...shouldn't it go to the line AFTER the 'else'? That's what I want to happen.

Comment: its a silly mistake, used `=`instead of `==` . You are assigning instead of comparing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace `<% if current_user.name = review.user.front_name %>` with

```
<% if current_user.name == review.user.front_name %>
```

you put `=`, you have to put `==`

Comment: Thanks for all your help. They're all right, but just accepting this as it came in first. Isn't there also a '==='? What does that do?

Comment: regarding  '===' 

The general definition of the triple equals is that it will return true if both parts are identical or if the right part is contained within the range of the left.

`1 === 1 #true`
`(1..3) === 2 #true`

There are some other impacts as well

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby to check equality you should use double equal signs (`==`).

Also - 
Currently you are comparing the names. You should compare the objects (User) to avoid mistakes or even worse (security breaches).

```
<% if current_user == review.user %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just modify: `<% if current_user.name = review.user.front_name %>` to

```
<% if current_user.name == review.user.front_name %>
```

The `==`  ( double equal) Test for equal value..

Answer (score 1):

when you want to make conditional statement. you should compare your statement.
for example:

```
if number == 10
   print "Variable is 10"
elsif number == "20"
   print "Variable is 20"
else
   print "Variable is something else"
end
```

on your case please change the line:

```
<% if current_user.name = review.user.front_name %>
```

change intoenter code here

```
<% if current_user.name == review.user.front_name %>
```